# how to smart indexing regard to dates in a data with missing dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, indexing

I have a data frame like this:

```
id      date       value
1       2017-01-01  10
1       2017-01-01  20
1       2017-01-02  10
1       2017-01-02  15
1       2017-01-07  25
2       2017-05-01  10
2       2017-05-01  15
2       2017-05-20  30
3       2010-08-08  40
3       2010-08-11  20
3       2010-08-11  43
```

I want to add values for each date and to add and an index column regard to the dates for example, at last data should be like this:

```
id       date        value    index
1        2017-01-01  30       1
1        2017-01-02  25       2
1        2017-01-07  25       3   
2        2017-05-01  25       1
2        2017-05-20  30       2
3        2010-08-08  40       1
3        2010-08-11  63       2
```

Comment: `add and an index column regard to the dates` Please explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` and `cumcount`

```
df1=df.groupby(['id','date'],as_index=False).value.sum()
df1['index']=df1.groupby('id',as_index=False).cumcount().add(1)
df1
Out[167]: 
   id        date  value  index
0   1  2017-01-01     30      1
1   1  2017-01-02     25      2
2   1  2017-01-07     25      3
3   2  2017-05-01     25      1
4   2  2017-05-20     30      2
5   3  2010-08-08     40      1
6   3  2010-08-11     63      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas [.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is your friend.

```
>>> df
    id       date  value
0    1 2017-01-01     10
1    1 2017-01-01     20
2    1 2017-01-02     10
3    1 2017-01-02     15
4    1 2017-01-07     25
5    2 2017-05-01     10
6    2 2017-05-01     15
7    2 2017-05-20     30
8    3 2010-08-08     40
9    3 2010-08-11     20
10   3 2010-08-11     43
```

group the data by the date and the id so that it won't be summed with `.sum()`. `as_index=False` makes it so the date column doesn't become the index. `sort=False` makes it so that it doesn't sort by dates.

```
>>> g = df.groupby(['date', 'id'], as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
>>> g
      date  id  value
2 2017-01-01   1     30
3 2017-01-02   1     25
4 2017-01-07   1     25
5 2017-05-01   2     25
6 2017-05-20   2     30
0 2010-08-08   3     40
1 2010-08-11   3     63
```

It's a bit ambiguous what you mean by the second part but assuming it means that the cumulative sum of equal ids:

```
>>> g['index'] = g.assign(count=1).groupby('id').cumsum()['count']
>>> g
        date  id  value  index
2 2017-01-01   1     30      1
3 2017-01-02   1     25      2
4 2017-01-07   1     25      3
5 2017-05-01   2     25      1
6 2017-05-20   2     30      2
0 2010-08-08   3     40      1
1 2010-08-11   3     63      2
```

here we assign `g['index']` to the cumulative sum of the `count` column we give the dataframe to be equal to one for each element.

If what you actually meant was the cumulative sum of each similar months, this can be done by grouping by `df.date.dt.month` and applying a similar method.